# Error: unable to run browserify in production (Heroku)

Tags: heroku, browserify

I've setup Browserify in development and it works great. But when I try pushing the application to Heroku, the push fails.

> remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
>
> remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
>
> remote:        rake aborted!

**Error:**

> remote:        BrowserifyRails::BrowserifyError: Unable to run
>   node_modules/.bin/browserify. Ensure you have installed it with npm.

I can confirm `browserify` is in `package.json`.

```
"browserify": "~10.2.4",
"browserify-incremental": "^3.0.1",
```

And that the files do exist in that location.

[image]

Note that the application was recently moved from running on `Webrick` to `Puma` but I see no indication here of that as an issue.

I'm not really sure where to start troubleshooting this. Could anyone share advice on what I should try next, or what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way to handle this issue:

***Configure Heroku to use multi-buildpack***

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

***Create .buildpacks file***

***Create .buildpacks file for the multi-buildpack to make sure node.js is compiled before ruby.***

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

***Install browserify with --save***

rake assets:precompile in heroku deploy expects browserify to be installed in .node_modules directory. So move it from devDependencies to dependencies.

```
npm uninstall browserify --save-dev
npm install browserify --save
```

Now try to deploy again!

```
git push heroku master
```

It should work now.

Comment: For reference, use `heroku buildpacks:set` for creating buildpacks - worked for me.

Comment: If you're seeing /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory -- make sure that nodejs set before ruby in your buildpacks. see answer below

Answer (score 2):

Use `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs`.

*heroku-buildpack-multi* and use of `.buildpacks` file has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this today. Here's what worked for me

1. Changed browserify to a regular dependency as the accepted answer did.
2. Reordered buildpacks to put `heroku/nodejs` first.

Changed `package.json` from this

```
"devDependencies": {
  "browserify": "^12.0.1",
   ...
}
```

To this

```
"dependencies": {
  "browserify": "^12.0.1",
  ...
}
```

Reorder buildpacks

The initial output of `heroku buildpacks` was

```
1. heroku/ruby
2. heroku/nodejs
```

So I did

```
$ heroku buildpacks:remove heroku/ruby
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby
```

Which changed it to

```
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku/ruby
```

Comment: just a note, your ordering in both lists is the same